# How to Remove all packages which is installed by dpkg from debs

Tags: package-management

I used to install packages by `dpkg -i *.deb` as I have all deb (with dependencies) in one folder.

Now Is there any  Reverse process of `dpkg -i *.deb` to remove all packages installed from debs.

(`dpkg -r <pkgname>`is not helpful because it requires package-name instead of deb file and not accept *.deb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dpkg` can extract the package name (with a bit of help). The only serious problem here is just chaining them together and that's where `find` steps in.

```sh
find -iname '*.deb' -exec dpkg --info '{}' \; | awk '/Package:/ {print $2}' | xargs -r -- sudo apt-get remove
```

That isn't tested but it should work.

Comment: I tried This and It's Working But dpkg shows error while removing some packages if other packages depends on them.    So. I tried "apt-get remove" Instead of "dpkg" -r  in that folder Containing Deb's. And It's Working Well.

Comment: @Pandya I noticed your edit bounced. Sorry about that. I've altered my answer to account for your comment.